# Crystal Reports PrintToPrinter throws exception after a time working fine

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

We have a WPF application that, among other things, prints reports approximately every two minutes using async sintax. The report is made using **SAP Crystal Reports, version for Microsoft Visual Studio 13.0.15.1840**. The computer in which application has been developed has also **SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine 64-bit 13.0.15.1840**. Below is the code for async code:

```
private async void StartAsyncOperation()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_isActive)
                {
                    await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        PrintTravelSheet();
                    });
                    await Task.Delay(_delayPrinterTime);
                }
                else break;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                SendWarningAlerts(string.Format("Error!!! You should be worried! \n {0}", e));
            }
        }
    }
```

The application is deployed to a computer with Windows Server 2012 with **SAP Crystal Reports runtime 64-bit 13.0.8.1216**. Below is the code used by **PrintTravelSheet** for printing:

```
try
        {//_hojaViajera is my Crystal Report
            _hojaViajera = new HojaViajera();
            InitializeTravelSheet(printerConfig, tracking, configBits);
            System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings printerSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
            printerSettings.PrinterName = printerConfig.PrinterName;
            _hojaViajera.PrintToPrinter(printerSettings, new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings(), false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //here I send emails with error log
        }
        finally
        {
            _hojaViajera.Close();
            _hojaViajera.Dispose();
        }
```

Usually the application works fine for two weeks or a little more, but after that time the thread that handles printing operations crashes and I receive the following exception:

```
** **Message Error: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.InternalException: There are not enough free System Resources to perform this operation.
Error formatting Field Object.
Error in File temp_1d4e04c2-7dc4-4896-a347-edc086582c07 {BFFFC1AF-E765-4FF0-BBEC-02929B533486}.rpt:
Low system resources.. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: There are not enough free System Resources to perform this operation.
Error formatting Field Object.
Error in File temp_1d4e04c2-7dc4-4896-a347-edc086582c07 {BFFFC1AF-E765-4FF0-BBEC-02929B533486}.rpt:
Low system resources..
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.GetPage(PageRequestContext pPageRequestContext)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.GetPage(PageRequestContext pageReqContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.HandleException(Exception exception)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.GetPage(PageRequestContext pageReqContext)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.QueryPageSettingsEventHandler(Object sender, QueryPageSettingsEventArgs e)
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.OnQueryPageSettings(QueryPageSettingsEventArgs e)
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument._OnQueryPageSettings(QueryPageSettingsEventArgs e)
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.PrintLoop(PrintDocument document)
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.Print(PrintDocument document)
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.Print()
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.PrintToPrinter(PrinterSettings printerSettings, PageSettings pageSettings, PrintLayoutSettings layoutSettings, Boolean reformatReportPageSettings)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(PrinterSettings printerSettings, PageSettings pageSettings, PrintLayoutSettings layoutSettings, Boolean reformatReportPageSettings)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(PrinterSettings printerSettings, PageSettings pageSettings, Boolean reformatReportPageSettings)**
**
```

Then I just close the application and start over again and all comes back to normal. So far I have not been able to reproduce the error on my machine or even on the server. Any help or workaround is welcome.